# Custom video player within angular component

Tags: angular, custom-controls

Here I have made a custom video player within an angular component (player.component) and embedding that player.component selector to app.component.html. Everything is working fine but when I loop over the (player-selector) or use player.component selector twice as sibling, then custom controls works only on the first  and rest items come with default controls.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-player></app-player>  // everything within this component selector and works just fine
```

but

```
// custom player works only with the first one and others with default controls
<app-player></app-player>
<app-player></app-player>
```

Here I need a solution to render multiple videos using *ngFor with this single component. Give me an idea to use my custom controls efficiently for multiple videos to play within a single page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dear members, need a solution please...

Answer (score 0):

Try
`<app-player *ngFor="let item of itemArray"></app-playep>`

pass parameters from itemArray with @Input

Or put it in div like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of itemArray">
  <app-player></app-player>
</div>
```

if it does not help, try out generating dynamic components.  [Angular Dynamic Components](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)